# Sequence in the complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

$f_n: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$

$f_n(x)=x^n$ in the complete metric space of bounded functions equipped with the supremum metric.

Is it a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: What is $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^n\;$ ...:   (1) when $\;0\le x<1\;$ ? When $\;x=1\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be Cauchy. The normed space you considered is complete, hence $f_n$ would have an uniform limit if it was Cauchy. On the other hand the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is not continuous and so it can't be uniform limit of continuous functions.